# Derivative of complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Can anyone please help obtain the partial derivative of $\Im(\arctan(x+iy))$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, respectively.

actually this value can be plotted in the $x$-$y$ plane, as shown by follows:

[image: $\Im(\arctan(x+iy))$]

If the gradient or the partial derivative can not be obtained, please give me reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $$F=\arctan(x+iy)$$, we have $$F'_x=\frac{1}{1+(x+i y)^2}$$ $$F'_y=\frac{i}{1+(x+i y)^2}$$ Expanding, the imaginary parts are then given by $$\Im(F'_x)=-\frac{2 x y}{4 x^2 y^2+\left(x^2-y^2+1\right)^2}$$ $$\Im(F'_y)=\frac{x^2-y^2+1}{x^4+2 x^2 \left(y^2+1\right)+\left(y^2-1\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f = u+iv$ is a complex-valued function, then we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x},\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$$

so the partial derivatives of the real resp. imaginary parts of $f$ are the real resp. imaginary parts of the partial derivatives of $f$.

For a holomorphic $f$, the situation simplifies, since

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z) = f'(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f'(z),\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z) = f'(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = i f'(z).$$

For $f(z) = \arctan z$, we have $f'(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$, so the partial derivatives of the imaginary part are

$$\frac{\partial \Im f}{\partial x}(z) = \Im \frac{1}{1+z^2},\qquad \frac{\partial \Im f}{\partial y}(z) = \Re \frac{1}{1+z^2}.$$

It remains to write $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ in Cartesian form:

$$\frac{1}{1+z^2} = \frac{1+\overline{z}^2}{\lvert 1+z^2\rvert^2} = \frac{(x^2-y^2+1) - 2ixy}{(x^2-y^2+1)^2 + 4x^2y^2}.$$